# How to use an icon from react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons that exists in the library?"

Tags: react-native

I used the 'account' icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons,' but I'm encountering a console warning that says 'export function addLog(log: LogData): void { const errorForStackTrace = new Error();' and the icon is not being applied.

```
     <Tab.Screen 
        name="Account" 
        component={AccountScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({color, size}) => (
            <Icon name="account" size={size} color={color} />
          ),
        }} 
      />
```

Some icons are applied correctly, and others are not. Even though I found them on the 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons' website and used the code, it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO! try to format all your code as `code` with {} or three ticks. Sometimes, for variable names, for example, just **bold** works